# How to reduce the number of queries required to get this result

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, codeigniter

I'm writing an application on top of CodeIgniter to better organize my ebook collection. I'm nearly done, but I realize my 'browse' page is running far too many queries - two per book - to get their information. Obviously not at all ideal, especially since I have about 1000 books to put into this system.

I currently have one model function which gets all of the books (will eventually be modified to take parameters - that's the next step) and another that gets the meta information for each returned book. The second function is the one which makes two queries for each book - one to get the information in the book table and another to get the tags associated with the book. Here are the two model functions:

Get the list of books:

```
function get_books() {
    $this->db->select('isbn')->order_by('title');
    $query = $this->db->get('books');
    $result = $query->result();
    return $result;
}
```

Get the book meta information:

```
function get_book_info($isbn) {
    // Grab the book from Amazon
    $amazon = $this->amazon->get_amazon_item($isbn);

    // Get the book info
    $this->db->select('title, publisher, date, thumb, filename, pages');
    $query = $this->db->get_where('books', array('isbn' => $isbn));
    $bookResult = $query->row();

    // Get the book's tags
    $this->db->select('tag');
    $this->db->from('tags AS t');
    $this->db->join('books_tags AS bt', 'bt.tag_id = t.id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('bt.book_id', $isbn);
    $this->db->order_by('t.tag');
    $tagQuery = $this->db->get();
    foreach ($tagQuery->result() as $row) {
        $tagResult[] = $row->tag;
    }
    $tagResult = implode(', ', $tagResult);

    // Send data
    $data = array(
        'isbn' => $isbn,
        'thumb' => $bookResult->thumb,
        'title' => strip_slashes($bookResult->title),
        'file' => $bookResult->filename,
        'publisher' => strip_slashes($bookResult->publisher),
        'date' => date('F j, Y', strtotime($bookResult->date)),
        'pages' => $bookResult->pages,
        'tags' => $tagResult,
        'rating' => $amazon->Items->Item->CustomerReviews->AverageRating,
        'raters' => $amazon->Items->Item->CustomerReviews->TotalReviews
    );
    return $data;
}
```

I'm certain there's a way to write one or two queries that will gather all the records into objects I can then filter through, rather than having to write two queries for each one, but I have no idea where to even start trying to write that. Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks much,
Marcus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some help from this topic and in others in creating a better query, I was able to resolve this with the following code:

```
function get_book_info() {

    /*
     * SELECT b.isbn, b.title, b.publisher, b.date, b.thumb, b.filename, b.pages, t.tag
     * FROM books AS b
     * INNER JOIN books_tags AS bt ON b.isbn = bt.book_id
     * INNER JOIN tags AS t ON bt.tag_id = t.id
     * ORDER BY b.title, t.tag
     */

    $this->db->select('b.isbn, b.title, b.publisher, b.date, b.thumb, b.filename, b.pages, t.tag');
    $this->db->from('books AS b');
    $this->db->join('books_tags AS bt', 'b.isbn = bt.book_id', 'inner');
    $this->db->join('tags AS t', 'bt.tag_id = t.id', 'inner');
    $this->db->order_by('b.title, t.tag');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();

    $counter = '';
    $record = $meta = $tags = array();
    $count = count($result);
    $i = 1;

    foreach ($result as $book) {
        // If this is not the last row
        if ($i < $count) {
            // If this is the first appearance of this book
            if ($counter != $book->isbn) {
                // If the meta array already exists
                if ($meta) {
                    // Add the combined tag string to the meta array
                    $meta['tags'] = implode(', ', $tags);
                    // Add the meta array
                    $record[] = $meta;
                    // Empty the tags array
                    $tags = array();
                }
                // Reset the counter
                $counter = $book->isbn;
                // Grab the book from Amazon
                $amazon = $this->amazon->get_amazon_item($book->isbn);
                // Collect the book information
                $meta = array(
                    'isbn' => $book->isbn,
                    'title' => strip_slashes($book->title),
                    'publisher' => strip_slashes($book->publisher),
                    'date' => date('F j, Y', strtotime($book->date)),
                    'thumb' => $book->thumb,
                    'file' => $book->filename,
                    'pages' => $book->pages,
                    'rating' => $amazon->Items->Item->CustomerReviews->AverageRating,
                    'raters' => $amazon->Items->Item->CustomerReviews->TotalReviews
                );
                // Add the tag to the tags array
                $tags[] = $book->tag;
            } else {
                // All we need is the tag
                $tags[] = $book->tag;
            }
        // If this is the last row
        } else {
            // If this is the first appearance of this book
            if ($counter != $book->isbn) {
                // Grab the book from Amazon
                $amazon = $this->amazon->get_amazon_item($book->isbn);
                // Collect the book information
                $meta = array(
                    'isbn' => $book->isbn,
                    'title' => strip_slashes($book->title),
                    'publisher' => strip_slashes($book->publisher),
                    'date' => date('F j, Y', strtotime($book->date)),
                    'thumb' => $book->thumb,
                    'file' => $book->filename,
                    'pages' => $book->pages,
                    'rating' => $amazon->Items->Item->CustomerReviews->AverageRating,
                    'raters' => $amazon->Items->Item->CustomerReviews->TotalReviews
                );
                // Add the tag to the tags array
                $tags[] = $book->tag;
                // Add the combined tag string to the meta array
                $meta['tags'] = implode(', ', $tags);
                // Add the meta array
                $record[] = $meta;
            } else {
                // All we need is the tag
                $tags[] = $book->tag;
                // Add the combined tag string to the meta array
                $meta['tags'] = implode(', ', $tags);
                // Add the meta array
                $record[] = $meta;
            }
        }
        $i++;
    }

    return $record;
}
```

There may very well be a better way to handle this, but this was how my logic saw it. And only one query, total.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is:

1. Grab a sorted list of all of your books and their tags,
2. Style them out as HTML, with tags and ratings.

Grab your books *and* tags together, have a variable to keep track of the last ISBN you wrote out, and only build up your entry when the ISBN changes.  So, pull a set like this:

```
Book   | Tag
------ | ----------------
Book A | Fiction
Book A | Fantasy
Book B | Mystery
Book C | Science Fiction
```

Then, write out the "basic book info" for every time the book changes within your loop.  Obviously, you'll want more fields than just **Book** and **Tag** (e.g., **ISBN**).

If your Amazon information comes from Amazon, you're probably going to have no choice about making repetitive calls to their API (unless they have a "batch" mode or something, wherein you could submit an array of ISBN's?).

Comment: Agreed. I'm okay with the multiple calls to Amazon - that's all "nice to have" data. I've saved the core book metadata to the db. 

I like the sample resultset you show, but I don't have a clue how to write that sort of query. Any tips to get me started?

Comment: Inspired by your approach, I asked another question on how to generate the result above and implemented my solution based on it. Code is below.

Comment: Sorry to have been asleep while you solved it on your own ... but glad you got it!

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right: in the table *books* there is all the data about the books:
so doing this:

```
$this->db->select('*')->order_by('title');
$query = $this->db->get('books');
$result = $query->result();
return $result;
```

should return you all the data about your books and you shouldn't need to cycle again to get data.

Comment: I'm okay with the first query. I would rather have one extra query than have to hold the entire contents of my books table in memory every time someone wants to view a specific set. My question is more about the second model function. The first was supplied for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with CodeIgniter at all, but I think there are some general practices you can incorporate.

- If this is a browse page - isn't there pagination?  Paginating the results should drastically cut down the number of queries you have to run per page load.
- Have one function (say, `get_books_info()`) you call that retrieves all the tags & meta info for all the books returned by your `get_books()` function.  Then reference that array from your `get_book_info()`.  You can even trigger `get_books_info()` from `get_book_info()` - so you only need to do the work if you need the data.  Kind of lazy loading I think.

Comment: There will be pagination eventually, but I need to get the optimized queries first and then just apply the limits and offsets to them.

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_book_info() {

    /*
     * SELECT b.isbn, b.title, b.publisher, b.date, b.thumb, b.filename, b.pages, t.tag
     * FROM books AS b
     * INNER JOIN books_tags AS bt ON b.isbn = bt.book_id
     * INNER JOIN tags AS t ON bt.tag_id = t.id
     * ORDER BY b.title, t.tag
     */

    $this->db->select('b.isbn, b.title, b.publisher, b.date, b.thumb, b.filename, b.pages, t.tag');
    $this->db->from('books AS b');
    $this->db->join('books_tags AS bt', 'b.isbn = bt.book_id', 'inner');
    $this->db->join('tags AS t', 'bt.tag_id = t.id', 'inner');
    $this->db->order_by('b.title, t.tag');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();

    $counter = '';
    $record = $meta = $tags = array();
    $count = count($result);
    $i = 1;

    foreach ($result as $book) {
        // If this is not the last row
        if ($i < $count) {
            // If this is the first appearance of this book
            if ($counter != $book->isbn) {
                // If the meta array already exists
                if ($meta) {
                    // Add the combined tag string to the meta array
                    $meta['tags'] = implode(', ', $tags);
                    // Add the meta array
                    $record[] = $meta;
                    // Empty the tags array
                    $tags = array();
                }
                // Reset the counter
                $counter = $book->isbn;
                // Grab the book from Amazon
                $amazon = $this->amazon->get_amazon_item($book->isbn);
                // Collect the book information
                $meta = array(
                    'isbn' => $book->isbn,
                    'title' => strip_slashes($book->title),
                    'publisher' => strip_slashes($book->publisher),
                    'date' => date('F j, Y', strtotime($book->date)),
                    'thumb' => $book->thumb,
                    'file' => $book->filename,
                    'pages' => $book->pages,
                    'rating' => $amazon->Items->Item->CustomerReviews->AverageRating,
                    'raters' => $amazon->Items->Item->CustomerReviews->TotalReviews
                );
                // Add the tag to the tags array
                $tags[] = $book->tag;
            } else {
                // All we need is the tag
                $tags[] = $book->tag;
            }
        // If this is the last row
        } else {
            // If this is the first appearance of this book
            if ($counter != $book->isbn) {
                // Grab the book from Amazon
                $amazon = $this->amazon->get_amazon_item($book->isbn);
                // Collect the book information
                $meta = array(
                    'isbn' => $book->isbn,
                    'title' => strip_slashes($book->title),
                    'publisher' => strip_slashes($book->publisher),
                    'date' => date('F j, Y', strtotime($book->date)),
                    'thumb' => $book->thumb,
                    'file' => $book->filename,
                    'pages' => $book->pages,
                    'rating' => $amazon->Items->Item->CustomerReviews->AverageRating,
                    'raters' => $amazon->Items->Item->CustomerReviews->TotalReviews
                );
                // Add the tag to the tags array
                $tags[] = $book->tag;
                // Add the combined tag string to the meta array
                $meta['tags'] = implode(', ', $tags);
                // Add the meta array
                $record[] = $meta;
            } else {
                // All we need is the tag
                $tags[] = $book->tag;
                // Add the combined tag string to the meta array
                $meta['tags'] = implode(', ', $tags);
                // Add the meta array
                $record[] = $meta;
            }
        }
        $i++;
    }

    return $record;
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are not good answers - please trim your answer, add some commentary, just describe the relevant bits.